# Storing 6 billion floats for easy access in files

Tags: php, python, file, struct, storage

I need to save 250 data files an hour with 36000 small arrays of [date, float, float, float] in python, that I can read somewhat easily with PHP. This needs to run for 10 years minimum, on 6tb of storage.

What is the best way to save these individual files, I am thinking python struct. But it starts to look bad for the job with large data amounts?

example of data

```
a = [["2016:04:03 20:30:00", 3.423, 2.123, -23.243], ["2016:23:.....], ......]
```

Edit:
Space, is more important than unpacking speed and computation. Since the space is very limiting.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, why files and not just use a db?

Comment: Wow can i sign up for a notification when that 10 year period expires with a success?

Comment: @HankyPanky  I'm guessing it's for some kind of satellite, unmanned/unmonitored submerged drone, or such where they cant update the drive they install.   Maybe a remote sensor of some type.

Comment: Just a note: 36000 arrays per hour implies you have 10 arrays per second, but your sample timestamp's precision is seconds.

Comment: Good point found out I don't need year and day though, because of the file structure. Its structural data and the hardware can be updated in size, but the request was for it to be able to handle 10 years data from the start. And the amount of storage is allready specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have 250 data providers of some kind, which are providing 10 samples per second of (float, float, float).

Since you didn't specify what your limitations are, there are more options.

---

**Binary files**

You could write files of fixed array of 3*36000 floats with [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), at 4 bytes each gets you at 432.000 bytes per file. You can encode the hour in the directory name and id of the data provider in file name.

If your data isn't too random, a decent compression algorithm should shave enough bytes, but you would probably need to have some sort of delayed compression if you wouldn't want to lose data.

**numpy**

An alternative to packing with struct is [numpy.tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile), which stores the array directly to file. It is fast, but always stores data in C format, where you should take care if the endian is on target machine is different. With [numpy.savez_compressed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) you can store a number of arrays in one npz archive, and also compress it at same time.

**JSON, XML, CSV**

A good option is any of the mentioned formats. Also worth mentioning is [JSON-lines format](http://jsonlines.org/), where each line is a JSON encoded record. This is to enable streaming writing, where you keep a valid file format after each write.

They are simple to read, and the syntactic overhead goes away with compression. Just don't do string concatenation, use a real serializer library.

**(SQL) Database**

Seriously, why not use a real database?

Obviously you will need to do something with the data. With 10 samples per second, no human will need so much data, so you will have to do aggregations: minimum, maximum, average, mean, sum, etc. Databases already have all this and with combination of other features they can save you a ton of time you can otherwise spend on writing oh so many scripts and abstractions over files. Not to mention just how cumbersome the file management becomes.

Databases are extensible and supported by many languages. You save a datetime in database with Python, you read datetime with PHP. No hassles with how you are going to have to encode your data.

Databases support indexes for faster lookup.

My personal favourite is PostgreSQL, which has a number of nice features. It supports [BRIN index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/brin-intro.html), a lightweight index, perfect for huge datasets with naturally ordered fields, such as timestamps. If you're low on disk, you can extend it with [cstore_fdw](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw), a columnar oriented datastore, which supports compression. And if you still want to use flat files, you can write a [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) ([also possible with Python](http://multicorn.org/)) and still use SQL to access the data.

Comment: Hmm limitations is I need to be able to load the data fast for graphs, and only have 6tb of space, I am allready creating statistics for a database so the user is able to see which files are usefull fast. All data needs to be preserved, so throwing any away is not a option.
I still think struct is the cheapest option in a matter of storage, but I think I will do some tests, to see if json with gzip or struct with the same will fill the least.

Comment: And what do you mean by delayed compression, tried a quick google, but it didn't yield anything usefull.

Comment: I think limiting yourself to 6TB for 10 years is not real. In 10 years we should have disks of at least about 20TB if I'm conservative. Also, expecting no disk will die in 10 years is unrealistic.

Comment: You should definitely create a test dataset, if possible one, that mimics expected data, and test.
By delayed compression I meant that if you do not want to lose data, you need to write records to dist as they arrive and compress them once the file is not expected to change.

Comment: Ahh yeah with the delayed compression, that is what I am doing, calculating statistics and saving to HDD. Created som tests and found that the only way the data came under @Alex Blex calculated was with struct and gzip. So I'm going with that. JSON with gzip stil gave me 1MB per file where struct in averege gives 300KB.
The HDD's are in a hardware raid so changing disksizes is not completely straight forward, hence the needed limitations so there want be to many expenses down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're consuming the files in the same language, avoid language specific formats and structures.  Always.

If you're going between 2 or more languages, use a common, plain text data format like `JSON` or `XML` that can be easily (often natively) parsed by most languages and tools.

If you follow this advice and your storing plain text, then use compression on the stored file--that's how you conserve space.  Typical well-structured `JSON` tends to compresses really well (assuming simple text content).

Once again, choose a compression format like gzip that's widely supported in by languages or their core libraries. PHP for example has a native function `gzopen()` and python has lib\gzip.py in the standard python library.

Comment: Thank you, were considering either that or pure binary aproach (the C way), seems like I will just end up going with this.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is possible without extremely efficient compression.

```
6TB / 10 year/ 365 days / 24 hrs / 250 files = 270 KB per file.
```

In ideal case. In real word size of cluster matters.

If you have  36,000 “small arrays” to fit into each file, you have only 7 bytes per array, which is not enough to store even proper datetime object alone.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, I only need date down to day and hour, since the rest will be in the folder structure or in the heading of the file, that leaves me with 1 int and 3 floats. 
But from the calculations I can allready see I need to think more about the data than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to my mind if you want to save space. You better store only values and discard timestamps. Produce files with only data and make sure that you created a kind of index (formula) that given a timestamp (year/month/day/hour/min/sec...) results in the position of the data inside of the file (and of course the file that you have to go for). Even, if you check twice you will discover that if you use an "smart" naming scheme for the files you can avoid to store information about year/month/day/hour, since part of the index could be the file name. That all depends on how do you implement your "index" system, but pushing to an extreme version you could forget about timestamps and focus only in data.

Regarding data format, as aforementioned, I would definitively go on language independent format as XML, JSON... Who know which languages and possibilities will you have in ten years ;)

Comment: There will be missing data points in many of the files, so this could potentially make large files without needing it with empty data, but the mapping structure I will do.

Comment: GIven the fact that you are planning to have series of empty data then maybe you should still follow the aforementioned way, but compressing your files asdap you close them and in the while you process the following one. Compression works pretty well in these scenarios and will reduce the space wasted for the empty data.